# Map values from one dataframe column properly to other column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames in which one column is common. I want to compare both the data frames and map the value of the 2nd column in data frame 2 to the first if matched properly.
For example, I have one data frame say treasury_shares with column entity_Id another data frame say soiValues with columns entityId and attribute_value. I want to compare the entity_Id and create a new column in data frame A with attribute_value values properly assigned to entity_Id in the data frame treasury_shares as they were in data frame soiValues.

Currently what I am doing is
`treasury_shares.insert(6, "SOI priority",soiValues['attribute_value'], True)` I am only inserting the attribute_value values as it is what I get from the database in the form of data frame soiValues. But the SOI priority values are assigned in an improper manner in the data frame treasury_shared to the respective entity IDs with my approach. Wrong attribute_value values are been assigned.

Can anyone help me in building the logic for this? Will the below code work?

```
for index, row in treasury_shares.iterrows():
    for index,row in soiValues.iterrows():
        if (treasury_shares['entity_id']==soiValues['entity_id']):
            treasury_shares['SOI priority']=soiValues['attribute_value']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `merge` function in Pandas library

A quick demo for the same -

```
import pandas as pd  
      
lst = [['A', 1], ['B', 2], 
       ['C', 3], ['D', 4]] 
   
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['x1', 'x2']) 

lst2 = [['A', 'Hello'], ['B', 'Hola'], 
       ['C', 'Hi'], ['D', 'Hey']] 
     
df2 = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['x1', 'x3'])

df1.merge(df2,on='x1',how='left')
```

If there are values of `x1` in `df1` with no corresponding values in `df2` you will get a row with `NaN` in `x3` column

If there are values of `x1` in `df2` with no corresponding values in `df1` it will not show up in the output currently but can be added by tinkering with the `'how'` parameter

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: @PratikPathare What did not work please be more descriptive with the issue, is this not what you wanted? or was it something else?